Is it possible to control the order of invoking custom Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core?
I have a tag helper in my _Layout file that looks for a value in DataView.
The value is stored in DataView using a different tag helper.
It works if I use the second tag helper in a View, but when I use it in _Layout the first tag helper executes before the value is written to DataView.
Is there any way of making sure other tag helpers have been invoked?
In _Layout (site:head, which relies on the icon tag helper):
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SLT.Home.Spirit</title>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("STYLE", required: false)

    <site:head />
</head>

In view:
<site:view />

<icon google-name="test" />

